# Using data from SQL Table instead of File Geodatabase Table

Tags: arcpy, sql-server

Does anyone know of a method to use the table from SQL Server table using OS Authentication, instead of a File Geodatabase Table in ArcPy?

I have been using the below to reference the table

```
tableTemplate = r"C:\Data_table.gdb\DataTable"
```

where DataTable consists of a set of rows and columns. I have created a similar table in sql server and want to use the same instead of the above File Geodatabase Table.

I have tried the below so far with no luck:

```
arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(out_folder_path="Database Connections",

                                          out_name="DataTable.sde",

                                          database_platform="SQL_SERVER",

                                          instance="gis-server",

                                          account_authentication="OPERATING_SYSTEM_AUTH",

                                          database="TemporaryDatabase",

                                          version_type="TRANSACTIONAL",

                                          version="dbo.DEFAULT")
tableTemplate = r"Database Connections\TemporaryDatabase.sde\DataTable"
```

Am I doing something wrong somewhere? I get an error : "Database Connections\DataTable.sde\DataTable does not exist or is not supported." I am using arcpy.CopyRows_management later in the script.

Comment: Does the Connection work when you double-click it in ArcMap/ArcCatalog?

Comment: @BERA yes it does

Comment: Same, ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset C:\Users\DebS\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcCatalog\TemporaryDatabase.sde\DataTable does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (CopyRows).

Comment: Doesn't still, same error.

Comment: Are you saying that the `CreateDatabaseConnection` in your script successfully creates a .sde file that you can later use in ArcCatalog? If so, I think you need `tableTemplate = r"Database Connections\DataTable.sde\DataTable"` at a minimum (and possibly also the appropriate schema/owner name before `DataTable`).

Comment: I just checked and I see that it's generating a .sde file in C:\Users\DebS\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcCatalog\DataTable.sde but when I am manually trying to connect to it using ArcCatalog its giving an error: "Failed to connect to the database. Faliure to access DBMS server", which explains the reason why I am getting an error in the script too. Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way I could generate a .sde file that works?

Comment: Are you needing to _create_ this connection every time you run the script?  If you have a working connection already in ArcCatalog can you use that instead?  I realise this was from a year ago, but the comment still stands for anyone else that may have this issue. You don't always need to create a connection in arcpy, you can use existing ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that isn't right is that you specified `out_name` as *DataTable.sde*, and then use *TemporaryDatabase.sde* to open the connection.

You could try to create a new .sde file from within ArcCatalog first, so that you know you have all the correct settings. Perhaps you do not have the right privileges.